# Viewing issues completed in released version

Tags: jira

Is it possible to view a list of completed tasks in a released version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. If you go in a current JIRA version to your project, on the tab name `Versions` and click on a released version, you have a view with only the issues of that release.

[image]

You may alternatively create a query with the following:

- Select from the menu: `Issues > Search for Issues`
- Select your project in the list of projects.
- In the blue box below, press `Refresh Search`.
- Select the version under `Fix for`.
- Press the button `Search` above.

If you need that search again, just copy the link under [image] and keep it in your bookmarks or [image] it as a filter.